# How to use Pipeline and GridSearch model on test data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I am using `Pipline()` and `GridSearch()` during training and validation to eliminate data leakage. My question is, after creating a pipeline and calling it in GridSearch, how do I use the final returned model on my test data? Is it as simple as using the typical `model.predict(...)` as if pipeline wasn't being used?

But more specifically, how can I use this returned model to iterate through test data and predict each row as it comes in a loop?

The code that creates the model is as follows :

```
x,y = balance_dataset(df)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.8, random_state = 0)

pipe = Pipeline([('sc', preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()), 
             ('SVM', svm.SVC(decision_function_shape = 'ovr', kernel = 'poly'))])

candidate_parameters = [{'SVM__C': [0.01, 0.1, 1], 'SVM__gamma': [0.01, 0.1, 1] }]

clf = GridSearchCV(estimator = pipe, param_grid = candidate_parameters, cv = 5, n_jobs = -1)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

After calling pipeline and GridSearch, is it possible to then iterate over test data in a loop, or does is a pipelined model only capable of predicting the entire test dataset?

Comment: No sure I follow; once `clf` is fitted, you can use `clf.predict` with whatever data you want

Comment: So whether I'm isolating just one example from my test set, or using my entire test set, `clf.predict()`, the predicted result will not change? Does `clf.predict()` transform the test data as soon as its called?

Comment: Still don't follow; what do you mean "*the predicted result will not change?*"?. `clf.predict()` is practically a function; what you get depends on what you give as input. And it uses the whole pipeline indeed.

Comment: I'll expand a little bit. I used to not use pipeline, I used to run `.fit(X_train)` and then `.transform(X_train)` and `.transform(X_test)`, however this leads to data leakage in cross-validation. But I suppose my confusion lies with the fitting and transformation of test data. Does calling `predict()` automatically transform unseen test data, and does the number of observations I input to `predict()` skew or mess with the transformation process and hence the final prediction?

Comment: It cannot skew or mess anything; since `sc` is part of your pipeline, `clf.predict` will apply `sc.transform` to whatever data you pass, it will not re-fit anything.